# Error in Flight Order API ,Amadeus Flight Order API

Tags: api, amadeus

Is there is any error or do we need to do something else?
we are facing a critical issue with the Flight Order API that is preventing us from placing flight orders through the API.

The error message we are receiving is as follows: [Insert specific error message here]. This error occurs consistently whenever we attempt to use the Flight Order API for making flight reservations. We have thoroughly reviewed our integration code and confirmed that there are no issues on our end.

```
<?php
$clientId = 'notshared';
$clientSecret = 'notshared';
$tokenUrl = 'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token';
$orderEndpoint = 'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/booking/flight-orders';
$authPayload = [
    'client_id' => $clientId,
    'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
];

$ch = curl_init($tokenUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($authPayload));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if ($response === false) {
    echo "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
    exit;
}

$tokenData = json_decode($response, true);
if (isset($tokenData['access_token'])) {
    $accessToken = $tokenData['access_token'];

    $jsonData = '
    {
      "data": {
        "type": "flight-order",
        "flightOffers": [
          {
            "type": "flight-offer",
            "id": "1",
            "source": "GDS",
            "instantTicketingRequired": true,
            "nonHomogeneous": false,
            "validatingAirlineCodes": ["AF"],
            "itineraries": [
              {
                "segments": [
                  {
                    "departure": {
                      "iataCode": "JFK",
                      "terminal": "1",
                      "at": "2023-06-01T08:00:00Z"
                    },
                    "arrival": {
                      "iataCode": "LHR",
                      "terminal": "2",
                      "at": "2023-06-01T20:00:00Z"
                    },
                    "carrierCode": "AA",
                    "number": "1001",
                    "aircraft": {
                      "code": "777"
                    },
                    "operating": {
                      "carrierCode": "AA"
                    },
                    "duration": "PT12H",
                    "id": "1"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "travelerPricings": [
              {
                "travelerId": "1",
                "fareOption": "STANDARD",
                "travelerType": "ADULT",
                "price": {
                  "currency": "USD",
                  "total": "500.00",
                  "base": "400.00"
                },
                "fareDetailsBySegment": [
                  {
                    "segmentId": "1",
                    "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                    "fareBasis": "XYZ",
                    "class": "M",
                    "includedCheckedBags": {
                      "weight": 23,
                      "weightUnit": "KG"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "travelers": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "dateOfBirth": "1985-05-25",
            "name": {
              "firstName": "John",
              "lastName": "Doe"
            },
            "gender": "MALE",
            "contact": {
              "emailAddress": "john.doe@example.com",
              "phones": [
                {
                  "deviceType": "MOBILE",
                  "countryCallingCode": "1",
                  "number": "1234567890"
                }
              ]
            },
            "documents": [
              {
                "documentType": "PASSPORT",
                "birthPlace": "New York",
                "issuanceCountry": "US",
                "issuanceCountryCode": "US",
                "number": "123456789",
                "expiryDate": "2025-05-25",
                "issuanceDate": "2020-05-25",
                "nationality": "US",
                "holder": true
              }
            ]
          }

        ]
      }
    }
    
    
    ';


    $headers = [
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
        'Content-Type: application/vnd.amadeus+json'
    ];

    $ch = curl_init($orderEndpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $response;
    
} else {
    echo "Failed to obtain access token.";
}
?>
```